# In Bamboo, how do I pull a component library repository to a fixed location to avoid per-branch duplication?

Tags: windows, git, continuous-integration, bamboo

I have several projects which use code from a large set of component libraries. These libraries are under source control.

The libraries repository contains all the libraries used by all my projects and contains multiple versions of multiple libraries. Each library/version pair lives in its own folder. Each of my projects identifies the specific library/version pairs it needs through the folder paths of the references in its project file.

For example `$(LibraryPath)\SomeLibrary\v1.1.5`

Please note that the libraries repository is only ever *added to*. No changes are made to stuff already in the repository. Ever.

I have been of course been able to configure my build plan to pull the libraries repository to a `libraries` subfolder of the working directory. So far so good. However, using the auto branch management feature of Bamboo, this setup means that the libraries repository is cloned for each and every branch in all projects.

Not funny. No, really, not funny...

What I would like to do is:

- pull the libraries repository in each build plan
- but pull it to a fixed location that is the same for all build plans
- it doesn't have to be an absolute path
- but it does need to be outside the working directory of the current build plan to avoid unnecessary duplication

Unfortunately the `Checkout Directory` of the `Source Code Checkout configuration` task in a Bamboo build plan doesn't allow me to specify either an absolute path or a relative one that goes "up" for one or more levels from the working dir. The hint text explicitly states "(Optional) Specify an alternative sub-directory to which the code will be checked out." And indeed, specifying something like `..\Library` gets punished with the message "Checkout to parent directory is forbidden".

I have seen information on the "artifact sharing" feature of Bamboo. This will probably work, but it seems like overkill for what I want to achieve.

**What would be the easiest and least complicated way to achieve my goal using Atlassian's Bamboo Continuous Integration?**

Out-of-the-box alternatives are welcome, but please don't direct me to any products that require intimate CLI use and/or whose documentation assumes (extensive) knowledge of 'nix and/or Java setup. I am on Windows and spoiled rotten by powerful (G)UI's.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem - with a repository weighing in at around **2GB**.
I'd like to simply "**git checkout myBranch**" and "**git clean -fxd**" instead of cloning every time (which should save a lot of time and disk space).  However I also like Bamboo's automatic trigger with new branches showing up.

Like the OP, I'd love to be able to put "**..\SharedDirectory**" in the "**CheckoutDirectory**" for the 
"Source Code Checkout" task but it won't let me go out above the \JOB_KEY\ folder

One possible solution is: replacing the "Source Code Checkout" task with the two git commands above. That way I can specify exact when/where/how to do the checkout. I think there may be problems with the initial checkout in this case - but once that is solved, all subsequent branches would use the same shared folder, and no more pulling down 2GB every time.

Comment: Nice out of the box thinking. Out of curiosity: do you think this would work with "gated check-ins"? In other words: run this for every push to remote (or pull request) and commit only if the build succeeds? My doubt is that this commit would still need a checkout in order to work?